# How do I force Reactor to run subscribe() code on non-daemon threads?

Tags: java, project-reactor

*This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77953921/are-project-reactors-error-handlers-run-in-some-daemon-by-default) which is, in turn, a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77952090/how-do-you-catch-exceptions-in-project-reactor/77952277)*

To make these consumers make any difference and produce any output to standard output, you can't run this code as is:

```java
@Test
void test() {
    WebClient.builder().build()
        .get()
        .uri("https://httpbin.org/status/404")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .subscribe(
                s -> System.out.println("Success: " + s),
                t -> System.out.println("Failure: " + t.getMessage())
        );
}
```

My first working solution was adding a `sleep()` call. That's when I realized my code (those println's) was run on daemon threads

I want the JVM to actually execute one of those print statements instead of calling it quits right away, without `block()`ing. To achieve that, I need to get Reactor to allocate regular threads, not daemons

I tried to do that by appending

```java
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newParallel("my-scheduler", 5, false))
```

to the method chain (notice the `false`, should mean "non-daemon"). Sadly, Reactor still ran the code on its default daemons (no logs)

I tried some other `Scheduler`s supplied by the factory (including some "bounded elastic" `Scheduler`, whatever that means). No change

How do I force Reactor to run `subscribe()` code on non-daemon threads?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.
Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have. You can use `observeOn()` to switch to a different thread when a new value is produced in the source.

Comment: @Progman I want the JVM to actually execute one of those print statements instead of calling it quits right away. To achieve that, I need to get Reactor to allocate regular threads, not daemons

Comment: That's not how Reactor works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am not exactly sure about what you're trying to achieve.
If I understand well, you're trying to better understand Reactor execution model and how to control it. Therefore, this post won't be straight-forward "do this" answer. Instead I will try to provide insights about Reactor control flow/threading model, and how to work with it*.

## Reactor lifecycle: assembly and execution

First and foremost, let's talk about assembly vs execution. When you use Reactor methods, most of the time, you *assemble* a pipeline of operations over a stream of incoming messages. Pipeline execution requires a call to either `subscribe()` or `block()`.

Each intermediate operation is a hidden subscription that sinks upstream flow messages/values, process them, then send result to a downstream subscription (the next operation in the chain.
Each operation/subscription can specify a *scheduler* (i.e. a pool of thread) it would prefer to be run in.
For example, `flatMap` specify the `parallel scheduler` by default, to allow to concurrently process many values.

It means that a pipeline run can involve many threads from many contexts, and also that involved threads won't be "hogged" by the pipeline.
More on that in the next section.

## Subscription

When calling any form of `subscribe()`, Reactor triggers execution on the calling thread. But, and it is important: it still runs *asynchronously*, and it does *not block the thread it is running in/scheduled on*. It means that when you do something like this:

```java
public static void main() {
    Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4).subscribe(i -> System.out.println("Next value: "+i));
    System.out.println("Hello from main method");
}
```

All prints will be done from the main thread, but still, you cannot determine in what order, because subscribe() will return before consuming the flux. The flux will execute on the main thread, but only when it is not busy with some other task. It means that in the example above, Main thread can very well exit main method before the flow finished execution.

If you subscribe manually to flux, and you want to synchronize/join its completion with a specific point in your program, you have to add a synchronisation barrier yourself. If we use the example above, and want to ensure the main method does not exit before the flux ends, we either have to use `block()` (which can cause problems, notably with WebClient code that uses a blocking incompatible thread pool by default), or add a barrier ourself, like:

```java
public static void main() {
    var barrier = new CountDownLatch(1);
    Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4).subscribe(
        i -> System.out.println("Next value: "+i),
        error -> barrier.countDown(),
        barrier::countDown
    );
    System.out.println("Hello from main method");
    
    // Wait for flux completion before exiting method
    barrier.await();
}
```

For more in-depth explanations on subscriptions, you can check this other answer: [What is the threading model of Spring Reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75127969/2678097).

*Note*: in the linked answer, you will also find another (inefficient) way to wait for the completion of a flux.

## Managed execution

Most of the time, you do not want or need to call subscription yourself. When working with any Spring reactive technology, like Webflux, Cloud Stream, etc. you return a publisher (flux or mono) to Spring components, which will take care of scheduling and running your pipeline correctly.

When using Webflux, for example, Flux execution or cancellation is bound to Netty asynchronous IO, to properly complete or cancel HTTP responses.

When doing unit tests, you should use the `StepVerifier` or the `WebTestClient`, which in turn run your pipeline and ensure its completion.

Comment: Thank you! Does it mean the answer to my question is "There's no way"?

Comment: There is no way to use `subscribe()` as you ask in your question. This is the role of `block()`. But *block* has other problems, so I tend to avoid it as much as possible. If you really want to use *subscribe*, and still need to wait for flux completion to continue code execution, then the *CountDownLatch* example is the way to go.